# Why aren't wildcarded classpaths working for me?

Tags: java, classpath, wildcard

Im using JDK 1.6.0.25.  I'm trying to include a classpath like so:

```
-cp .;Server.jar;Util.jar;../jars/**/*;./lib/*
```

Whatever I do, this doesn't work and I end up having to explicity refer to the files within those directories.  Any idea how to debug this or does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: someting about the part [/jars/**/* ] tells me that this might be the problem. Did you mean [/jars/*.* ] ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [Settings the classpath](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html) (Section "Understanding class path wildcards")

You cannot use the Ant or Bash style wildcards, you can only use it in the 'standard' way.

Comment: You can't even use the full range of 'standard' wildcards. **Only** `somedirectory/*` is supported.

Comment: huh? so your saying that /* is supported or not?? I wonder why Oracle/Sun didn't implement this differently... maybe a security issue?

Answer (score 2):

From the [Java application launcher documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html):

> Class path entries can contain the
>   basename wildcard character *, which
>   is considered equivalent to specifying
>   a list of all the files in the
>   directory with the extension .jar or
>   .JAR.

Note that there is no mention of the sequence `**`, which is not going to be interpreted in any sensible manner by the java executable. You cannot search recursively within sub-directories as well:

> Subdirectories are not searched
>   recursively. For example, foo/* looks
>   for JAR files only in foo, not in
>   foo/bar, foo/baz, etc.

In other words, all child directories of the `jars` directory in the classpath entry `../jars/**/*` will have to be explicitly specified if you intend to use wildcards directly from the command-line.